# SQL query to find the count of non null values in each column of table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I can find the count of non null values by typing each column name, but is there a way to write it without manually typing the column names as I have 100+ columns in my table.

```
select 'col1Name', count(col1Name) from table where col1Name is null
union
select 'col2Name', count(col2Name) from table where col2Name is null
union ...
select 'col20Name', count(col20Name) from table where col20Name is null
```

Comment: You can use a spreadsheet to generate the code.

Comment: @gordon-linoff spreadsheets would require some manual work. I was looking for a more automated solution as I need to run this query on multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case operation here

```
select 
  sum(case when a is null then 1 else 0 end) A,
  sum(case when b is null then 1 else 0 end) B,
  sum(case when c is null then 1 else 0 end) C
from T
```

Comment: Hi @dsk, here again I would need to manually enter the column names & it would become a very long query with 100+ lines, is there any other way where I don't have to manually type column names?

Comment: If it is one time activity - You can do this in Excel file and get the condition ready and paste in your code..